# Ruby on rails - Simple form not displaying errors for radio select. Other errors display fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, devise, simple-form

I have a user registration form (Devise) with 4 elements; Username, email, password and 'user type'. User type is a boolean and is displayed as a radio select on the form.

Errors for Username, email and password show no problem, but I get no errors showing if a user doesn't select one of the radio buttons. Validation IS in place, and the form won't send without one of the radio buttons selected, but I get no errors.

The form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="role-selector">
            <p class="type-sel-txt"><%= t('front.whattype') %></p>
            <label for="artistuser">
                <%= f.radio_button :artist, "1", :id => "artistuser" %>
                <span class="artistuser-sel"><%= t('front.bandm') %></span>
            </label>
            <label for="eventuser">
                <%= f.radio_button :artist, "0", :id => "eventuser" %>
                <span class="eventuser-sel"> <%= t('front.evento') %></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: t('forms.login.user'), label: false %>
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, placeholder: t('forms.login.email'), label: false %>
        <%= f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: t('forms.login.password'), label: false %>
        <div id="passcheck"></div>
        <%= f.button :submit, t("forms.login.signup"), id: "register-btn" %>
    <% end %>
```

User.rb:

```
  validates_inclusion_of :artist, in: [true, false], on: :create
```

Registration works without a problem, my only issue is the error not showing. I'm not sure if it is necessary to paste any more of my code, but if so I'll update with whatever is required.

Comment: There is no error, because validation is always valid in this case. I mean, if user doesn't select anything, value `artist` is false, and false meets your requirement, so there is no error.

Comment: The value of artist isn't false as it defaults to `nil` if nothing is selected. This can be confirmed as the form won't send if the `artist` boolean isn't selected in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As opposed to simple form's `f.input` which handles all related tags besides the input itself (the label tag, the error message tag), `f.radio_button` handles only the input field, because it is actually [a helper from `ActionView`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button), not simple form.

Simple form generates a **`span` with the "error" class** by default when a field has some errors attached. I guess you will have to render the span yourself, in a similar way as you did for the field labels:

```
<div class="role-selector">
  <p class="type-sel-txt"><%= t('front.whattype') %></p>
  <label for="artistuser">
     <%= f.radio_button :artist, "1", :id => "artistuser" %>
     <span class="artistuser-sel"><%= t('front.bandm') %></span>
  </label>
  <label for="eventuser">
     <%= f.radio_button :artist, "0", :id => "eventuser" %>
     <span class="eventuser-sel"> <%= t('front.evento') %></span>
  </label>

  <!-- show error for the artist attribute, if present -->
  <% if resource.errors['artist'].present? %>
    <span class="error"><%= resource.errors['artist'] %></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure it whole out what's happening but you can try some hack kinda thing

```
<%= f.radio_button :artist, "1", :id => "artistuser", :selected => f.object.artist %>
```

and then you can check whether it is present or not

```
<% if f.object.artist.blank? %>
  Display Your Error Message
```

Just a rough idea but with little modification you can make it work, let me know if there's any problem.